# How to create an instance of smsManager in kotlin with the given context of an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

```
private fun getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(context: Context, subsId: Int): SmsManager {
        val smsManager = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            context.getSystemService(SmsManager::class.java) as SmsManager
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < M")
        }
        val smsManagerInstanceForSubsId = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            smsManager.createForSubscriptionId(subsId)
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < S")
        }
        return smsManagerInstanceForSubsId
    }
```

I am using above code to create an smsManager Instance but the code is showing error at

```
context.getSystemService(SmsManager::class.java) as SmsManager
```

below is the error it is showing

Cannot cast null object to non-null object.

Answer (score 0):

**I didn't get any null exceptions when I ran it**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textView = TextView(applicationContext)

        getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(applicationContext, 1)
        Log.d("smsManager1 ", "succeed")
        getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(textView.context, 2)
        Log.d("smsManager2", "succeed")

    }
    
    private fun getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(context: Context, subsId: Int): SmsManager {
        val smsManager = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            context.getSystemService(SmsManager::class.java) as SmsManager
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < M")
        }
        val smsManagerInstanceForSubsId = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            smsManager.createForSubscriptionId(subsId)
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < S")
        }
        return smsManagerInstanceForSubsId
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know why it is showing me this error : java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.telephony.SmsManager

Comment: Hey sidnio can you explain : When i removed 'as SmsManager' code compiled successfully 
from this : context.getSystemService(SmsManager::class.java) as SmsManager
to this : context.getSystemService(SmsManager::class.java)

Comment: You clear the project cache and try it